# UITableView - Multiple Selection - Can I change my title based on the number of cells selected?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have a normal view controller which contains one `tableview` object. I have extended the viewcontroller to use `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate`

My `tableview` allows multiple selection, and I am able to track the number of rows selected using `tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows.count` within the `willSelectRowAt()` method

I am setting a `tableview` title within the `viewForHeaderInSection()` method. However there does not appear to be a way to link the two, to make the title dependant on number of rows selected

For example

If tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows.count < 1, title = Hello

If tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows.count = 2, title = Good Morning

etc

Thanks

Comment: please put your code here, so it will be easy to understand what you have tried and what makes the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement withe proper view

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
   viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? { --- }
```

---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
    willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath? {
    if let header = tableview.headerView(forSection:indexPath.section) as? YourCustomHeader {
       // here update the model with the new header name to avoid dequeuing problems 
       header.yourLbl.text = "" // change here according to any logic
    }
}
```

--- With titleForHeaderAt

```
if let header = tableview.headerView(forSection:indexPath.section) {
       // here update the model with the new header name to avoid dequeuing problems 
       header.textLabel.text = "" // change here according to any logic
}
```